# how to bind labels for different numbers of values

Tags: asp.net

i had written this code to bind each text box values to labels this works for each single value but now i want label bind each and every values for numbers of times means i m using for loop for this so that i can bind different values and shows it dynamically for number of iterations  so how is it possible.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = TextBox1.Text;
    string order = TextBox2.Text;
    int qty = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
    int rate = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text);
    int discount = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
    int c = (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(TextBox4.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text));
    TextBox6.Text = c.ToString();
    int total = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);
    string j="";
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        j += i + "";

        Label1.Text = j + "customer name is:-" + name;
        Label2.Text = j + "order item is:-" + order;
        Label3.Text = j + "quantity is:-" + qty;
        Label4.Text = j + "rate of the item is:-" + rate;
        Label5.Text = j + "discount given to the item is:-" + discount;
        Label6.Text = j + "Total of the item is:-" + total;
    }

    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox4.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox5.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox6.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Can you come back and edit your question - break it up into coherent sentences, and use normal sentence casing, create a proper title, etc.? It would make it a lot easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are overwriting the value of each label... so in the end you are only left with the final values.

What you want to do is set the value of the label to its *previous value* **and** the *new value*:

```
Label1.Text += j + "customer name is:-" + name;
```

The `+=` is the same as:

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + j + "customer name is:-" + name;
```

For readability, you probably want something more like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{   
    Label1.Text += i + " customer name is:-" + name + "<br />";
    Label2.Text += i + " order item is:-" + order + "<br />";
    Label3.Text += i + " quantity is:-" + qty + "<br />";
    Label4.Text += i + " rate of the item is:-" + rate + "<br />";
    Label5.Text += i + " discount given to the item is:-" + discount + "<br />";
    Label6.Text += i + " Total of the item is:-" + total + "<br />";
}
```

And you need more error checking on things like `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)`. [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) throws an exception if the conversion fails.

If you get into big loops, you probably want to consider something like [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: but this code works for single value and i want loop for different numbers of values.

Comment: You need to clarify your question more. What other values are you talking about? Did you try this code?

Comment: suppose i enter one one name=mike,order=pizza,quantity=4,rate=200 buck,discount=10%,total=smthin.

Comment: now i want to enter another value with different values like name=narendra,order=soap,quantity=6,rate=5 bucks,discount=2%,total= something, i want label bind these to values simultaneously

Comment: I think what you want is something totally different. You don't allow for multiple inputs before the postback. You'll need to add more inputs or dynamically add more inputs with JavaScript. One set of inputs = one set of user data to use in your code behind.

Comment: so how is it possible to do so?